# Will Metropolis-Hastings always converge?

Tags: real-analysis

The title says it all - will Metropolis-Hastings *always* converge, like no matter which starting sample you choose?

Comment: Doesn't [ergodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm#Formal_derivation) (see point 2 in the uniqueness criteria list) guarantee that?

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke oh it seems like it from that link. Thanks! But you sound a little uncertain though?